# Read csv file into R that contains brackets at at the start and end of each line

Tags: r, csv

I have a text file that looks as follows

```
(abc,123)
(def,456)
(ghi,789)
...
```

In R, I would like to read this file as a csv. Therefore I need to get rid of the opening and closing brackets at the end of the lines. Do you have an idea how to achieve that?

Reading the file, removing the brackets and writing to a temporary file should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Why are these restrictions necessary?

Comment: If I continued tinkering, I'll bet I could get something that works using `pipe` and the unix command `tr`, sending the result directly to `read.csv`. Someone better than I with the shell side of that might be able to put the pieces together faster.

Comment: ...the tinkering was successful, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably go the `readLines` route, since the file needs to be manipulated first.  Then you can still use the `text` argument in `read.csv/table`

```
> writeLines(c("(abc,123)", "(def,456)", "(ghi,789)"), "yourfile.txt") 
   ## put your data in a file
> txt <- gsub("[()]", "", readLines("yourfile.txt"))
> read.csv(text = txt, header = FALSE)
#    V1  V2
# 1 abc 123
# 2 def 456
# 3 ghi 789
```

or

```
> read.table(text = txt, sep = ",")
#    V1  V2
# 1 abc 123
# 2 def 456
# 3 ghi 789
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, this seems to work (on my Mac):

```
read.table(pipe("tr -d '()' < ~/Desktop/paren.txt"),header = FALSE,sep = ",")
   V1  V2
1 123 abc
2 456 def
3 789 ghi
```

Comment: You have a Mac? Are you a data scientist?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No, I can't possibly be a data scientist. I'm too good at statistics and too bad at programming to qualify.

Answer (score 4):

Crazy idea time, but you can create your own `colClasses` definitions and use them in `read.table`, like this:

```
setClass("strippedL")
setClass("strippedR")
setAs("character", "strippedL",
      function(from)  as.character( gsub("(", "", from, fixed=TRUE)))
setAs("character", "strippedR",
      function(from)  as.numeric( gsub(")", "", from, fixed=TRUE)))
```

Here's how it would be use. Replace the `text` argument with the `file` argument to access a file instead.

```
read.table(text = "(abc,123)
                   (def,456)
                   (ghi,789)", 
           sep = ",", header = FALSE, 
           colClasses = c("strippedL", "strippedR"))
#    V1  V2
# 1 abc 123
# 2 def 456
# 3 ghi 789
```

---

Less crazy (but slower) idea: try out `read.pattern` from the development version of "gsubfn":

```
library(gsubfn)
source("http://gsubfn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/R/read.pattern.R")

pat <- "^\\((.*),(.*)\\)$"
read.pattern("~/path/to/file.txt", pattern=pat, header = FALSE)
```

Comment: See my time test -- I was nice enough not to include the class definitions inside the actual function :-)

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the best way to deal with this sort of situation is to edit the source file prior to reading it into `R`. I can imagine no reason to avoid this that warrants writing some fancy `R` code to remove the brackets subsequent to reading in the data.

Open your choice of text editor and tell it (the editor) to remove all parentheses.  Save the file (to a new file if necessary), then open the new file with `read.csv` .

But if you must,

```
foo<- read.csv(your_file)
gsub('(','',foo)
gsub(')','',foo)
foo[,2]<-as.numeric(foo[,2])
```

EDIT:  ran a speed test:

```
paren1<-function(file) {
    foo<- read.csv(file)
gsub('[()]','',foo)
#gsub(')','',foo)
foo[,2]<-as.numeric(foo[,2])
}

setClass("strippedL")
setClass("strippedR")
setAs("character", "strippedL",
      function(from)  as.character( gsub("(", "", from, fixed=TRUE)))
setAs("character", "strippedR",
      function(from)  as.numeric( gsub(")", "", from, fixed=TRUE)))
paren2<-function(file) {
      foo<- read.table(file,sep = ",", header = FALSE, colClasses = c("strippedL", "strippedR"))
      return(invisible(foo))
}

library(microbenchmark)
# my "paren.txt" has 860 lines in it
microbenchmark(paren1('paren.txt'),paren2('paren.txt'))

Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 paren1("paren.txt") 3.341024 3.461614 3.486416 3.514639 4.060715   100
 paren2("paren.txt") 2.164631 2.251439 2.285007 2.322211 5.681836   100
```

So Ananda's solution is noticeably faster.  Oh well :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this work gsub("[()]","",foo) as a single line?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 str1 <- c("(abc,123)","(def,456)","(ghi,789)")
 library(qdap)
 read.table(text=unlist(bracketXtract(str1, "round")),sep=",")
 #  V1  V2
 #1 abc 123
 #2 def 456
 #3 ghi 789
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using the `gsub` function for the first and second columns of the data.frame:

```
tmp <- read.table("tmp.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#tmp <- structure(list(V1 = c("(abc", "(def", "(ghi"), V2 = c("123)", 
"456)", "789)")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)) # to reproduce tmp

tmp
tmp[,1] <- gsub("(", "", tmp[,1], fixed = TRUE)
tmp[,2] <- gsub(")", "", tmp[,2], fixed = TRUE)
tmp
```